# request for member 'constantCoordinateValue' in something not a structure or union error in core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, charts, core-plot

i am trying to draw bar chart for my app using core plot as give on here
 http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CPTestApp-iPhone/Classes/CPTestAppBarChartController.m?r=1dcee044c4981113f38b3445880c88da14bdb40e

i am getting error for

```
CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)barChart.axisSet;
CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;  
x.constantCoordinateValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
```

error is coming for above line

error: request for member 'constantCoordinateValue' in something not a structure or union
and same error for following

```
y.constantCoordinateValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
```

i hope some know how to solve this

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
```

instead

```
x.constantCoordinateValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
```